# Unable to access the modified value of a global variable from outside the function: Variable not updated

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, global-variables, global

Assuming the following snippet:

```
a = None

def set_a():
    global a
    a = 10+2

print(a)
```

The result is expected to be `12`, so why does it remain as `None` and won't update?
I've been looking for similar questions on stackoverflow but didn't find a proper explanation/solution. How exactly can I access the modified value of a global variable which has been updated inside a function from outside of it?
Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: You haven't run the function?

Comment: If you don't call `set_a()` it's never run, never executed, `a` doesn't change

Comment: @azro Shoot, you're right. I absolutely forgot about that- thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> a = None
>>> 
>>> def set_a():
...     global a
...     a = 10+2
... 
>>> set_a()
>>> 
>>> print(a)
12
```